# What are different ways to send form data to controller action in ASP.net MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-3, http-post

I want to post a form data which has grid kind of layout and a column in each row contains dropdownlist. selected value in the dropdown list maps to item id of that row.

I want to know what are the different ways to post this data to controller action in this case?

Passing as individual parameters is already ignored option as my form will have dynamic data and it may have n number of records. Am I correct in this thinking?

Thought of FormCollection, is this right choice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As always I would start by defining a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Values { get; set; }
}
```

then have a GET controller action which will populate a collection of this view model and in the corresponding view I would use editor templates:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Some column name</th>
            </tr>
       </thead>
        <tbody>
            @Html.EditorForModel()
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="submit value="OK" />
}
```

and in the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MyViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model MyViewModel
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
            x => x.SelectedValue,
            new SelectList(Model.Values, "Value", "Text")
        )
    </td>
</tr>
```

and finally this will post the selected values:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<MyViewModel> model)
{
    ...    
}
```

Comment: @Darin: A small doubt, isn't it redundant passing 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Values' for each row? Can't we send this list once for the entire view as this is same for all rows?

Comment: @JPReddy, yes, of course if the same dropdown must be shown on each row. Maybe I misunderstood the question and assumed that a different dropdown should be used on each row.

Comment: @Darin: Even I'm assuming that same dropdown list is used in all rows, in this case how should we design model to contain single list for all rows? any idea?

Comment: @JPReddy, you wrap the view model I showed in another view model. The main view model will contain the Values property (unique for the entire page) and it will have an IEnumerable property containing the data for the rows.

Comment: @Darin: would like to have your opinion on my answer below

Comment: @JPReddy, I prefer editor templates. I don't like writing foreach loops in my views. And when I see FormCollection passed as action argument instead of using a view model I simply cry.

Comment: @Darin: In my case my action only want to have the selected item for the row, so should I send entire model back to action even though it is not required? Little bit confused after your comment, can you clarify please?

Comment: @JPReddy, no you should not send the entire model. You should design a special view model which contains only what you need. Once again in my example I assumed that a single form is used and that the selected values of all drop downs are sent to the action. If you want to send the value only of a single row dropdown you should use multiple forms for each row, each with its separate submit button, ...

Comment: @Darin: How about sending dropdown list through viewdata instead of putting it in view model if it remains same for all rows?

Comment: @JPReddy, I hate `ViewData` and always recommend people to avoid it. Personally I never use it. Strongly typed views and view models are for me the correct way.